# return array_chunk in groups

Tags: php, arrays

I can usually do pretty decent with basic arrays, but this one has put my head vs the wall.

I am trying to pass some information (for a menu) through a function, and return it in a formatted fashion.

My desired end result is to send some information like this. I need to be able to repeat the array until it is empty in the event that I have a number of fields

```
$Sort = array('imgup.jpg','imagedn.jpg','Name','imgx.jpg','imagy.jpg','Name4');
NewSortBox($Sort);
```

and have an end result that would return like

```
<div>Name <img src='imgup.jpg'><img src='imgdn.jpg'></div>
<div>Name4 <img src='imgx.jpg'><img src='imgy.jpg'></div>
```

I have figured out that I have to use the Array_Chunk function to break the array, but I am not able to figure out how to make it properly use the foreach or loop functions.

```
function NewSortBox(&$array){

$newArray = array_chunk($array, 3, false);
$i = 0;
foreach ($newArray as $inner_array) {
    $i++;
    echo "<div>";
    while (list($key, $value) = each($inner_array)) {    
        echo "$key: $value"; 
        // Here is where I am totally lost, I want to acheive something like ??
        // echo "$value[1] <img src='$value[2]'><img src='$value[3]'>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help to get the desired result:

```
    $newArray = array_chunk($Sort, 3, false);

    foreach ($newArray as $inner_array) {
echo "<div>";
    list($a, $b, $c) = $inner_array;
echo $c.":".$b.":".$a; //arrange the variables as required
echo "</div>";
    }
```