# Grouping array elements with given number in php

Tags: php, arrays

Grouping array elements with given number in php.
How to group array elements using php?

I have the following array

```
array (size=10)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
   3 => int 4
   4 => int 5
   5 => int 6
   6 => int 7
   7 => int 8
   8 => int 9
   9 => int 10
```

I need group this array following model

```
0 => 
array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
1 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 4
   1 => int 5
   2 => int 6
2 => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => int 7
    1 => int 8
    2 => int 9
3 => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => int 10
```

How can i do this?
I tried following code.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
            $result[$i][] = $arr[$j];
        }
    }
```

Ihe result to this code given below

```
array (size=10)
0 => 
  array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
1 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
2 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
3 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
4 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
5 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
6 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
7 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
8 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
9 => 
 array (size=3)
   0 => int 1
   1 => int 2
   2 => int 3
```

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

`array_chunk($input_array, 3);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return array\_chunk in groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086674/return-array-chunk-in-groups)

Answer (score 0):

[PHP array_chunk documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/762403)

```
<?php

$array = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
    5 => 6,
    6 => 7,
    7 => 8,
    8 => 9,
    9 => 10
);
print_r(array_chunk($array, 3));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_chunk.asp

Comment: This is a comment.  Links alone are not answers.